# Moving the mortar after firing?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have to get 2 kills to complete an assigment on BF3. But the problem part is, whenever I start to use mortar, I get shown on the map with mortar icon (pretty normal) but I would like to move mortar after I have the shot, so I wont be a clear target.

Most of the times, another mortar guy kills me with mortar because he sees my location, but at killcam I see him with a gun (not mortar) and running around. So it means there must be a way to quit mortar screen and continue running around like nothing happened.

So how can I do it?

Comment: Please, edit the title to reflect more the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mortar is like a vehicle.  Once it is placed, automatically you are entered in it.  To get out of the mortar, press <kbd>E</kbd> (or whatever the exit vehicle button is on your platform) for a second or two to exit it. Then look at the mortar and hold <kbd>R</kbd> (or whatever the reload button is on your platform) to pick it up.

Note that the mortar can potentially be destroyed when you're not manning it, as "equipment".

You will only appear on the map once you fire your mortar.  Therefore, when you place it the first time - scan the map for the other mortar targets.  If you are already on the mortar and you happen to notice an enemy mortar, shoot one off and then exit immediately.

In kill-cam, you see him running around because he launched one off to you, then exited [ strategy featured above]

It is also a good idea to move around a lot.  Plant your mortar -> launch a few off -> exit the mortar -> pick it up / resupply yourself -> Move somewhere else, rinse and repeat

Comment: Besides that you carry ammobags. So just throw it for yourself and get a new mortar really quick. That's the way I do it :)